# Ajax jquery Post didn't send parameters

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I use this code to send a post request to another page. post call works but no parameter send to that page :

```
$.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "insertar.php", data:"tipo_tar:1&monto:" + "1000" + 
    "&n_m:" + "100" + "&refe:" + "100" 
    +"&usuario:" + "pcisneros01" 
    + "&email:" + "esadeghi@gmail.com" ,
    contentType:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    success: function(result)
    {
        alert(result);
        if(result.indexOf("SMS")>=0){
            $(".centro").hide();
            $(".content-area").hide();
            $("#bodythxRecarga").show();
        }
    }
});
```

I am confused. I comply all rules but in destination page I don't have any post data.

Comment: Your `$_SESSION` variables will be empty on page load. Do a `var_dump($_POST)` on your PHP page. This should show up in your alert (although `console.log(result)` is a lot easier.

Comment: The $_SESSION variable are not important. I want post data.

Comment: Replace all the `:` in your `data:` with `=`.

Comment: dont use return in insertar.php . Use echo statement

Comment: Don't edit the post to your answer. Post an answer instead. As this confuses readers and destroys the context. Edits should only contain neutral changes, unless done by the OP.

Comment: Try `data: "tipo_tar=1&monto=1000&n_m=100&refe=100&usuario=pcisneros01&email=esadeghi@gmail.com"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On `data:` replace `=` with `:` .

Example:

```
data:"tipo_tar=1&monto=" + "1000"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try Like  This

```
url: 'insertar.php',
type: 'POST',
data: {
    tipo_tar: 1,
    monto: 1000,
    n_m: 100,
    refe: 100,
    usuario: "pcisneros01",
    email: "esadeghi@gmail.com"
},
contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use "string" in data you need to replace `:` with `=`

```
 //your code
 data:"tipo_tar=1&monto=" + "1000" + 
      "&n_m=" + "100" + "&refe=" + "100" 
      +"&usuario=" + "pcisneros01" 
      + "&email=" + "esadeghi@gmail.com" ,
//your code
```

maybe whitout `+`:

```
//your code
 data:"tipo_tar=1&monto=1000&n_m=100&refe=100&usuario=pcisneros01&email=esadeghi@gmail.com" ,
//your code
```

I'm not sure but i think they are useless... if you try to create more readable code you may consider to use a plain Object for `data` (I like this way):

```
//your code
 data:{
      tipo_tar : 1,
      monto    : 1000,
      n_m      : 100,
      refe     : 100, 
      usuario  : "pcisneros01",
      email    : "esadeghi@gmail.com"
 },
//your code
```